# Rebase "fixup" commit into prior merge commit

Tags: git, git-rebase, squash, git-interactive-rebase

I have performed the following merge:

```
A---B---C---E (HEAD, merge of C and D)
           /
      D---|
```

But I noticed some issues in E, and fixed them in F:

```
A---B---C---E---F (HEAD)
           /
      D---|
```

I want to modify commit `E` so that it contains the "fixup" changes made in `F`.

When I try `git rebase -p -i HEAD~2`, it tries to create a **regular (not merge)** commit, and even tries to make me re-resolve the conflicts I already resolved when performing the merge for `E`.

**How do I fixup** commit `E` so it contains the changes made in `F`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git reset --soft E
git commit --amend
```

should be enough. It'll recreate a merge commit (with a different hash than `E`, let's call it `E'`) while inserting whatever changes you made between `E` and `F`.

Comment: `git reset --soft`is just a gem.

Comment: What if there was a `G` (`H`, `I`, ...) commit after `E`?

Comment: @DanM.then changes in these other commits would also be grouped within the new commit.